# vb.Net c# running batch file and streaming its output

Tags: c#, vb.net, batch-file

I have this problem in VB.NET in c#, I have this project where I need to run a batch file, which is easy enough. But my problem is I need to display everything that shows up on the batch file, in the cmd window, in a textbox, now, this code opens the file no problem:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\jwoow\\Desktop\\Server\\run.bat";
proc.Start().ToString();
```

but it doesn't move the code over to the textbox, this code transfers the last displayed line, but not the entire thing of the batch file and it also closes the cmd window, i need it to stay open:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users/jwoow/Desktop/Server/run.bat";
//this line hides cmd window
//p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();
StreamReader output = p.StandardOutput;
while (output.EndOfStream == false)
{
    string line = output.ReadLine();
    this.RunResults.Text = line;
}
```

o yea, the batch file is for a server, it displays the amt of users on it (updates ever 2 minutes) and shows different events taken by the users. so it is constantly updating.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Pause" command to keep the window open after execution.  The text that is outputted to the screen is going to be different for each program you are using.  Most programs allow you to display different output based on a parameter you give it.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a class and call the code.  Have the last step have a timer that calls a pause for two minutes and then have it loop back to the beginning at the end of the 2 minute delay.